# UISwitch shows up on other cells! Glitch?

Tags: ios, uitableview, uiswitch

I have 5 seperate sections in a table, 2 of the sections have customizable cells, when in EDITING mode, 2 of the sections produce an additional cell that will add a new cell to the list. My problem is that when I invoke edit mode, the `UISwitch` glitches! and decides to jump around, VERY SIMPLE code, just have NO IDEA why the UISwitch is jumping to different cells in DIFFERENT SECTIONS when it should NOT!

```
static NSInteger kCustomTextTag = 1;
static NSInteger kServiceTag = 3;
static NSInteger kConnectTag = 4;
static NSInteger kVibrateTag = 1;

- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath 
{    
    Profile_ManagerAppDelegate *appDelegate = [[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate];

    static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell";

    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
    if (cell == nil) 
    {
        cell = [[[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectZero reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier] autorelease];
        cell.hidesAccessoryWhenEditing = YES;
    }

    UISwitch *swService = nil;
    swService = [[[UISwitch alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(195, 8, 160, 27)] autorelease];
    [swService addTarget:self action:@selector(serviceSwAction:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventValueChanged];
    swService.tag = kServiceTag;

    UISwitch *swConnect = nil;
    swConnect = [[[UISwitch alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(195, 8, 160, 27)] autorelease];
    [swConnect addTarget:self action:@selector(connectSwAction:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventValueChanged];
    swConnect.tag = kConnectTag;

    UISwitch *swVibrate = nil;
    swVibrate = [[[UISwitch alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(195, 8, 160, 27)] autorelease];
    [swVibrate addTarget:self action:@selector(vibrateSwAction:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventValueChanged];
    swVibrate.tag = kVibrateTag;

    if(indexPath.section == 0)
    {
        //CGRectMake Method (x, y, width, height)
        custProfileNameLabel = [[[UITextField alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(10, 11, 290, 21)] autorelease];
        custProfileNameLabel.tag = kCustomTextTag;
        custProfileNameLabel.textAlignment = UITextAlignmentLeft;
        [cell.contentView addSubview:custProfileNameLabel];
        custProfileNameLabel.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
        custProfileNameLabel.userInteractionEnabled = NO;
        custProfileNameLabel.placeholder = @"Custom Profile Name";
        custProfileNameLabel.autocapitalizationType = UITextAutocapitalizationTypeWords;
        custProfileNameLabel.clearButtonMode = UITextFieldViewModeWhileEditing;

        //UIKeyboardTypeDefault;
        cell.selectionStyle = UITableViewCellEditingStyleNone;
        CustomProfile *cProf = [CustomProfile alloc];
        cell.textLabel.text = [cProf tName];
    }

    if(indexPath.section == 1)
    {
        if(indexPath.row == ([[appDelegate serviceArray] count]) && self.editing){
            cell.textLabel.text = @"Add a Service";
            cell.selectionStyle = UITableViewCellSelectionStyleNone;
            cell.accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryNone;
            swService.hidden = YES;
            return cell;
        }else{
            swService.hidden = NO;
            cell.selectionStyle = UITableViewCellSelectionStyleNone;
            cell.accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryNone;
            cell.textLabel.text = [[appDelegate serviceArray] objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
        }
        [cell addSubview:swService];
    }

    if(indexPath.section == 2)
    {
        if(indexPath.row == ([[appDelegate connectArray] count]) && self.editing){
            cell.textLabel.text = @"Add a Connection";
            cell.selectionStyle = UITableViewCellSelectionStyleNone;
            cell.accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryNone;
            swConnect.hidden = YES;
            return cell;
        }else{
            swConnect.hidden = NO;
            cell.selectionStyle = UITableViewCellSelectionStyleNone;
            cell.accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryNone;
            cell.textLabel.text = [[appDelegate connectArray] objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
        }
        [cell addSubview:swConnect];
    }

    if(indexPath.section == 3)
    {
        NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES); 
        NSString *documentsDirectory = [paths objectAtIndex:0]; 
        NSString *myPlistPath = [documentsDirectory stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"ProfileManager.plist"]; 
        NSDictionary *plistDict = [[NSDictionary alloc] initWithContentsOfFile:myPlistPath]; 

        NSString *value;
        value = [plistDict objectForKey:@"Custom Ringtone"];

        if(indexPath.row == ([[appDelegate ringArray] count]) && self.editing){
            cell.selectionStyle = UITableViewCellSelectionStyleNone;
            cell.accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryNone;
        }else{
            cell.selectionStyle = UITableViewCellSelectionStyleBlue;
            cell.accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryDisclosureIndicator;
        }

        cell.textLabel.text = value;
    }

    if(indexPath.section == 4)
    {
        if(indexPath.row == 0 && self.editing)
        {
            //cell.userInteractionEnabled = NO;
            cell.accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryNone;
            cell.textLabel.text = @"Vibrate";
            swVibrate.hidden = YES;
        }else{
            swVibrate.hidden = NO;
            //cell.accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryNone;    
            cell.selectionStyle = UITableViewCellSelectionStyleBlue;
            cell.textLabel.text = @"Vibrate";
        }   

        [cell.contentView addSubview:swVibrate];
    }

    return cell;
}
```

### Screenshot

[image]

Comment: heres another picture of another part of the glitch:

http://twitpic.com/qc3dx

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, the reason this glitch was made possible is because the Controls were created when creating the cell, so it just continued to create additional controls when view appeared.

If you are receiving this glitch too, make sure you create the controls at ViewDidLoad, or call a void, just dont create the controls in the cellForRowAtIndexPath:

Answer (score 1):

Nothing freaky is going on. This is normal behavior. Note the line

```
  UITableViewCell *cell = dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier ...
```

The tableview controller keeps a queue of previously used cells for efficiency purposes, and when you scroll a new section of the tableview into view, it may return a previously used cell for you to reuse (in which case the value of the returned `cell` would not be `nil`). If that used cell originally had a uiswitch embedded in it, you'll get that switch back again, even if the current cell doesn't use it.

You need to check in your cell allocation code whether the cell being given back to you is an existing one or not, and remove the switch if it's present and you don't want it.

Howard